# flutter toast not working while there is an error and work when there is no error

Tags: flutter, dart

In my app there is login and API and cubit so i need when click on the text Button to show a message is the status that come from the API true and another message when status is false the flutter toast work when the status is true and do not working when the status is false

````
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var emailController = TextEditingController();
    var passwordController = TextEditingController();
    // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
    var FormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    return BlocConsumer<ShopLoginCubit, ShopLoginStates>(
      listener: (context, state)
      {
        if (state is ShopLoginSuccessState) {
          if (state.loginModel.status == true) {
            print(state.loginModel.message);
            print(state.loginModel.data.token);
            Fluttertoast.showToast(
                msg: state.loginModel.message,
                toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                timeInSecForIosWeb: 5,
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 16.0);
          } else if (state.loginModel.status == false) {
            print(state.loginModel.message);
            Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: state.loginModel.message,
              toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
              gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
              timeInSecForIosWeb: 5,
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 16.0,
            );
          }
        }
      },```
````

Comment: What is the error exactly? Or it just doesn't work without saying anything? Is it at least printing the message in console? Maybe there's something wrong with the if statement

Comment: there is a message in console should be printed and it print when the status is true